# QFile Dialog doesn't display on the Top

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I have several Dialogs with window Flags as WindowStaysonTopHint. When I open QFileDialog it displays at the bottom of these dialogs. How to set window Flag for QFileDialog. I use the following code to display the dialog at the top but it doesn't work.

```
> QFileDialog *dialog=new QFileDialog(this);
> 
> dialog->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
> 
> dialog->setModal(true);
> dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysonTopHint);
> dialog->getExisitngDirectory(this,tr("Directory"),"\home",QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory()` is a static function, this means it is not called on the instance `dialog` as your code makes it seem. This also means the functions you called on your `dialog` instance have no effect.

The documentation states "`getExistingDirectory()` is a convenience function..." So you can get the same effect by using an instance of `QFileDialog`. The source code of `getExistingDirectory()` looks more or less like this

```
QFileDialogArgs args;
args.parent = parent;
args.caption = caption;
args.directory = QFileDialogPrivate::workingDirectory(dir);
args.mode = (options & ShowDirsOnly ? DirectoryOnly : Directory);
args.options = options;
// create a qt dialog
QFileDialog dialog(args);
if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    return dialog.selectedFiles().value(0);
}
return QString();
```

So you have to do something similar and add your setting of `WindowFlags`. It could look like this (haven't tested it):

```
QFileDialog dialog(parent, caption, directory, filter);
dialog.setFileMode(DirectoryOnly);

dialog.setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysonTopHint);

if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    return dialog.selectedFiles().value(0);
}
return QString();
```

Comment: Could you let me know the include file for QFileDialogArgs as I get an error incomplete type is not allowed? I tried qfiledialog_p.h but it says that it is not found.

Comment: This part of the code seems to be private to Qt (hence the suffix _p.h), but you should get the same effect by using the other constructor. I'll update the answer.

Comment: that would be great!